# Computer controlled electronics

Tags: usb, serial, stepper-motor, books, how-does-it-work

I have a reasonable amount of experience writing drivers for pre-existing hardware and I am looking to develop my skills and learn some more.

Can anyone recommend good angle, resource or starting point for beginning the development of computer controlled electronics?

I'd like to get to the point where I can control a series of motors using C or C # via usb/serial from my PC using a custom built circuit.

I realise that this question is anlittle vague but without already knowing the terminology, its hard to find a better resource than good ol' stack exchange.

Comment: What do you want the motors to do? do you want to drive Brushless DC or some other kind of motors like servos?

Comment: Specifically, I want them to drive a lever into a pushing up and down motion. But I was hoping for general advice such as a decent book or other resource so I can make lots of things as a hobby.

Comment: I think this is a very good question. Almost every hobbyist will find it great to connect their devices to a computer, right? Can't we make this a community wiki on how to connect your electronics to a computer? We could list different ways like PIC, ARM, parallel port, ...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is probably too broad to remain open, so I'll make this brief.  There are many development boards out there that interface to a computer in some form, like serial, USB, or over the network.

Serial is getting really old now and less used, and you don't have to do anything special to talk to a device over the network.  If you want to get into the low levels of talking to a device more directly, USB is probably a good thing to experiment with.  The state of USB drivers is far from ideal.  You can't make your own drivers anymore on 64 bit Windows systems without going thru a bunch of certification hassle and expense.  There is some generic USB driver that surfaces most things to the app level, which may allow ordinary people to still write app code for their own USB devices.  I haven't looked at this in detail yet, so could be off a bit.  There is also LibUsb on Linux and Windows.  I think that's a separate open source effort, but don't know what exactly its capabilities are.

So get a development board with some existing capabilities and documented USB interface, and give it a try.  There are many out there, including our own [ReadyBoard-02](http://www.embedinc.com/products/ready02).

Comment: I think the best bet for simplicity without having to get a demo board with intrinsic USB support is using something like RS-232 or RS-485 to a USB adapter. Obviously this isn't always an option, but it does allow a much simpler interface than dealing with the USB driver stack.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling motors is not often done directly from the PC - though it's powerful, the OS uses that power in ways that are unsuitable for real-time control applications. (There are "real time" updates available for Linux but that's a  complex and messy subject; and AFAIK the situation for Windows is much worse).

So typically you would use an external microcontroller performing the control, and give it instructions via RS232 or USB.

Probably the easiest system to learn the basics on is the Arduino - its community makes it well supported, easy to find help, and it's not expensive. You can program it using its own C-like environment, or even in Ada if you prefer.

As for motors moving levers, the simplest form of that is servos for radio control models, and Arduinos certainly support that.

With more experience you can move on to other microcontrollers, ARM based for more CPU-intensive tasks or MSP430 for low-power operation if you like.